Construction of a function with specific sign derivatives
I want to construct a two variable function that satisfy the following conditions

$f(x, t) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow s$,
$f(x, t) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow r-t$,
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}<0$,
$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial t}<0$,
$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}>0$,
$s>x$ and $t<r-x$, $x,t,r,s>0$.

I have tried so many variations around exponential, polynomials and both together but seems like really hard to satisfy condtion 4 if I have already proved other conditions.
I would appreciate any help or hints, like do u think it is possible? It is hard for me to believe that such functions does not exist.
Thank you in advance.

I do not understand how Conditions 1,2, and 6 agreed. Namely, suppose that $t$ is fixed. By Condition 6, $x<s$ and $x<r-t$. So if $r-t<s$ then the limit in Condition 1 is undefined and if $r-t>s$ then the limit in Condition 2 is undefined.

I mean, I think this enters the discussion below, the function $f(t, x)=(s-x)(r-t-x)$ satisifies these condition that u mention.

I do not think such a function is possible because there are at least two values of $x$ such that $f(x, t) \rightarrow 0$.
That is, we need: $f(s, t) \rightarrow 0$ and $f(r-t, t) \rightarrow 0$ for all $t$. However, $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} < 0$. That means, when we hold $t$ constant the function is strictly decreasing in $x$ and therefore cannot be 0 at two places unless $s = r - t$.

But i can construct $f(t,x) = (s-x)(r-t-x)$ this functions meets condtion 1,2 and 3, the conditions that u mentioned that cannot be satisfied all together.

$f(x,t) = (s-x)(r-t-x) = x^2 -x(s+r-t) + s(r-t)$ the derivative with respect to x is $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} = 2x - (s + r - t)$. It is not true that 3. is met for all x.

I mean if u write it like that is not clear, but if u derivate right away it is $\frac{df}{dx} = -(r-t-x) - (s-x)$ and it is negative due to condition 6. That is why I'm trying to work under condition 6 to avoid issues as u point out.
